# IE9 caches response even when request headers include 'no-cache'

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, caching, internet-explorer-9

From everything I've read, 'cache-control: no-cache' is the brick wall that tells the browser not to cache a response under any circumstances. But IE9 (in my VM - Microsoft's IE-specific VM running a Windows 7 environment) is still caching everything it can. Here's a sample request from my devtools Network tab:

```
Request          GET /main/data/status/logs?page=0 HTTP/1.1
Pragma           no-cache
Accept           application/json
Cache-Control    no-cache
Expires          -1
Referer          http://10.20.etc..
Accept-Encoding  gzip, deflate
User-Agent       Mozilla/5.0(compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host             10.20.etc..
```

(I've tried this without the "Expires" parameter too) - Then here's the response:

```
Response           HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type       application/json
Transfer-Encoding  chunked
```

There are loads of resources about response caching out there - especially dealing with IE - but I can't find any that don't ultimately say that 'no-cache' is the last line of defense here. It does the trick for my IE10 VM.

Any situation where these headers aren't enough?

Comment: do you have the "Always refresh from server" button enabled in the Network tab of dev tools? Does your VM have the correct system time?

see http://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-http-304-responses

download fiddler from http://telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Please read - https://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/12/10/two-simple-rules-for-http-caching/

Comment: @RobParsons I wasn't aware of that button, thanks. Unfortunately I need full functionality for users with no additional steps necessary on their end. Good to know for testing on my end though. Checked system time and it's correct. I'm going with the "generate fake query params" solution, even though it's not ideal.  For anyone stumbling on this who hasn't heard this approach - if the url for the request changes, the browser recognizes the request as unique and won't just grab the cached resource.

Comment: ```if (document.all && !window.atob) {   // feature-check IE9
        let text = "";
        const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            text += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
        }
        return `?update=${text}`;```

Comment: Here's what fixed it - I added "Cache-Control: no-cache" to the **response headers** from the server. This option exists for both request and response headers, so I was confused.